# how to write the polar form of $x^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2 - y^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2$?

Tags: polar-coordinates

$$x^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2 - y^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2\\
r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}\\
x^2/r^4-y^2/r^4$$

Convert $x^2-y^2$ to polar form
$$x=r\cos(\theta)$$
$$y=r\sin(\theta)$$
$$(r\cos(\theta))^2-(r\sin(\theta))^2=r^2 \cos(2 θ)$$

$$r^2 \cos(2 θ)/r^4= \cos(2\theta)/r^2$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct but use mathjax !

Comment: I like plain text for its ease of copying so if somone decides to mark it up please leave a copy in plain text

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How have you got over a thousand reputation points but you still do not use MathJax?

Comment: How can you watch (because reading would be an overstatement) your original post for more than 7.5 second and claim that you like palin text?? It is almost impossible to understand...!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: it is $$\frac{r^2\cos^2(\theta)-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}{(r^2)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

***Hint***

It should look like this in the end:

$$E=x^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2 - y^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2=\frac {x^2- y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}=\frac {\cos^2(\theta)- \sin^2(\theta)}{r^2}$$
$$E=\frac {2\cos^2(\theta)- 1}{r^2}=\frac {\cos(2\theta)}{r^2}$$
So it's correct...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

$$x^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2 - y^2/(x^2 + y^2)^2\\
\\
x^2/r^4-y^2/r^4 = $$

$$\frac{\cos 2\theta}{r^2}$$